# Kubernetes nginx ingress rewrite issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    namespace: default
    name: my-ingress
    annotations:
       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: $2
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hostname.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /api/v1(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: backend
              servicePort: 80
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is:

hostname.com/api/v1/anyurl should become hostname.com/anyurl when it goes to the backend.
hostname.com/anyurl should remain hostname.com/anyurl and go to the frontend.

The /api/v1 rewrite seems to work, but any urls going to the frontend gets rewrited to /. 
What I need is the rewrite rule to only apply to the /api/v1 path

Comment: Because of the rewrite rule it will rewrite all path, did you try to split your ingress?

Comment: If I create two ingresses it will work, but I was wondering if it is possible with one @night-gold

Comment: I don't think that it's a good idea... As I said your rewrite will apply to all path for your rules and if you  want all (by default) to go one way you need not to rewrite anything in this case... So the best way to do this should be to split your ingress to have one without and one with rewrite applied

Comment: Shouldnt nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: / work for my case?

Comment: You could test it, and in this case you could try the /(.*) suggested in the answer... Testing, with / and the other could give some results

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work for you -

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    namespace: default
    name: my-ingress
    annotations:
       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: $1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hostname.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: frontend
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /api/(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: backend
              servicePort: 80
```

I have just edited this, it works for me, please check for this. I guess we can troubleshoot

Comment: can you just try this by keeping /api there and removing /v1 for now, then we can troubleshoot

Comment: Hi @joelgullander, can you please try the edited approach. It works for me, I have incorporated this. If this works then we can try with /api/v1